# Access IIS site from android

Tags: android, iis

I am using Windows 8 Pro x64. When I try to connect to my laptop with the Android 4.1 tablet of my parents, I just get Hostname could not be resolved.

I found that it works with the IP address, but I need the hostname. Reasons for this are ajax  calls and https. Any idea how I can get it work?